# After upgrading spring boot to 3.0.6, getting Failed to resolve for the oauth endpoints from Webclient in Mac M1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netty, webclient, reactor-netty

After upgrading to spring boot 3.0.6, replacing the usages of RestTemplate to WebClient, starting to see :

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Failed to resolve 'auth-service-.com' [A(1)] and search domain query for configured domains failed as well: [xyz.com]
```

Tried all the solution mentioned in the different sites and github issues of netty, but none seems to work.

---

**Machine details :**

```
Darwin 22.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.3.0: Mon Jan 30 20:38:37 PST 2023; root:xnu-8792.81.3~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64
```

**Gradle dependencies :**

```
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.6'
//...
runtimeOnly : 'io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:4.1.76.Final:osx-aarch_64'
```

**Exceptions :**

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Failed to resolve 'auth-service-.com' [A(1)] and search domain query for configured domains failed as well: [xyz.com]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:136) ~[spring-webflux-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST https://xyz/oauth/token [DefaultWebClient]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET https://xyz/api/v1/something [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:136) ~[spring-webflux-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:204) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
```

**Detailed exceptions :**

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Failed to resolve 'auth-service-.com' [A(1)] and search domain query for configured domains failed as well: [xyz.com]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:136) ~[spring-webflux-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST https://xyz/oauth/token [DefaultWebClient]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET https://xyz/api/v1/something [DefaultWebClient]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:136) ~[spring-webflux-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:204) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.whenError(FluxRetryWhen.java:225) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenOtherSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:274) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onError(FluxContextWrite.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.maybeOnError(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:326) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:211) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.drain(SinkManyEmitterProcessor.java:471) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManyEmitterProcessor$EmitterInner.drainParent(SinkManyEmitterProcessor.java:615) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublish$PubSubInner.request(FluxPublish.java:602) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.request(FluxContextWrite.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:336) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.request(FluxContextWrite.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$DeferredSubscription.request(Operators.java:1717) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:192) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect$ClientTransportSubscriber.onError(HttpClientConnect.java:311) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onError(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:162) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
        at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.fail(AbstractPool.java:475) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
        at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.lambda$drainLoop$9(SimpleDequePool.java:429) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(FluxDoOnEach.java:186) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnectionAllocator$PooledConnectionInitializer.onError(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:560) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:241) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:315) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.SecurityReactorContextConfiguration$SecurityReactorContextSubscriber.onError(SecurityReactorContextConfiguration.java:191) ~[spring-security-config-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector$MonoChannelPromise.tryFailure(TransportConnector.java:587) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
        at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector.lambda$doResolveAndConnect$11(TransportConnector.java:394) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:557) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:629) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure(DefaultPromise.java:110) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver$2.operationComplete(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:86) ~[netty-resolver-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:583) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:559) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:629) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:118) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext$1.operationComplete(DnsResolveContext.java:236) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:557) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:629) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:118) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is fixed by adding these following environment variables :

- `-Dvertx.disableDnsResolver=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Comment: Where to set those variables ? in the spring profiles ?

Comment: They are JVM arguments